# Disable TFS check-in permissions at the server or collection level

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I want to deny/restrict users from checking-in/out files in TFS. We are using TFVC with 2017.1 TFS.

I know I can do this at project level but that will be cumbersome as we have 200 projects. Is this something doable at root or collection level. I just want Collection administrators to have access but no one else.

Comment: Hi Sam, any update on this ticket, have you figured out your issue? jessehouwing is right, did you get a chance to implement the latest comment that he suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Nope, i'm working on the script piece and keep posted about the progress. Thanks for following-up and thanks to @jessehouwing for replying with alternatives.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your kindly response. Once you have figured out the issue, feel free to share it here, which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the Security page for any of your Team Projects in the collection, like:

```
https://account.visualstudio.com/project-name/_settings/repositories?itemPath=%24%2Fproject-name
```

Then change the `itemPath` to `$/`. That should bring up the security page for the whole collection:

```
https://account.visualstudio.com/project-name/_settings/repositories?itemPath=%24%2F
```

[image]

> Screenshot from Azure DevOps, I no longer have TFS 2017 at hand.

Or use Team Explorer's Source Control Explorer to get to the Security dialog inside Visual Studio.

[image]

Set the appropriate denies here and that should cascade down.

Comment: I thought about this too. But the challenge here is the groups. We use role based AD groups for TFS security. So for 200 projects, we have 800 AD groups (200*4 roles per project). With this approach, I need to deny 800 groups.

Comment: If the naming is reasonable, that's easy to script. Tfssecurity.exe is your friend in this case. You could use an approach similar to this one, though you'd need to do a little research on the correct name space and token structure. The approach would be the same. https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

Comment: Or use a dynamic ad group that auto-includes the 200 similar groups, then deny those. We use these to create groups based on ad properties and dynamically select members. I suppose that should work for groups of groups as well... Or script AD.

Comment: Nope. I tried your second approach but it didn't work for me. I DENIED all permissions for a user at root $/ however that user has ALLOW permission set on individual projects. I verified that user can still check-in and check-out files.

Comment: Then you probably need to script to re-enable inheritance at each project level. Sorry about that...